# SQL Server 2008 R2 table access times

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, statistics

Does SQL Server maintain statistics for each table on read, write, update times etc?

What we are wanting to know which tables our ERP applications spend the most time and begin looking for ways to optimize the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, SQL Server doesn't keep track of those statistics by table name. But you could look at DMVs like [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to see which *queries* are taking the longest.

```
SELECT [sql] = SUBSTRING
(
  st.[text],
  (s.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
  (CASE s.statement_end_offset 
    WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), st.[text]))
  ELSE s.statement_end_offset END
  - s.statement_start_offset)/2
), s.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.[sql_handle]) AS st
WHERE s.execution_count > 1
AND st.[dbid] = DB_ID('Your_ERP_Database_Name')
ORDER BY total_worker_time*1.0 / execution_count DESC;
```

Of course you can order by any metrics you want, and quickly eyeball the first column to see if you identify anything that looks suspicious.

You can also look at [`sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to identify procedures that are consuming high duration or reads.

Keep in mind that these and other DMVs reset for various events including reboots, service restarts, etc. So if you want to keep a running history of these metrics for trending / benchmarking / comparison purposes, you're going to have to snapshot them yourself, or get a 3rd party product (e.g. [SQL Sentry Performance Advisor](http://sqlsentry.net/performance-advisor/sql-server-performance.asp)) that can help with that and a whole lot more.

*Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: Thank you for the info.  We obviously have been looking for a feature which does not exist in the version of MS SQL we have installed (we also run DB2, Oracle, Informix etc)

We will script the commands as you suggest, and also look into SQL Sentry PA.

Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

You could create a SQL Server Audit as per the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Josh-gallaher

We were **not** aware of _SQL Server Audit_.

Thank you for pointing this out.
In the near future we will look at implementing this on our SQL Server. Have to jump through a few approval hoops, but should be do-able.

In the short term, we will run scripts on the commands suggested by **Aaron** as we have time constraints imposed by management.

Thanks again for replying

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does capture the information you're asking about, but it's on a per index basis, not per table - look in sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats and sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.  You'll have to aggregate the data based on object_id to get table information.  However, there are caveats - for example, if an index is not used (no reads and no writes), it won't show up  in the output.  These statistics are reset on instance restart, and there's a bug that causes them to be reset in index_usage_stats when an index is rebuilt (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739566/rebuilding-an-index-clears-stats-from-sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats).  And, there are notable differences between the outputs from the DMVs - check out Craig Freedman's post for more information (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/10/30/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-and-sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats.aspx).

The bigger question is, what problem are you trying to solve by having this information?  I would agree with Aaron that finding queries that are taking a long time is a better place to start in terms of optimization.  But, I wanted you to be aware that SQL Server does have this information.

Answer (score 0):

we use sp_whoisActive from [Adam Mechanics blog](http://whoisactive.com). 
It gives us a snap shot of what is currently going on on the server, and what execution plan the statements are using.
It is easy to use and free of charge.